# Maximum update exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and no background in reactjs.
I'm always getting an error: "Maximum update exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

As you can see in the below code I want to switch watchlist on a button press. The error occurs eventhough the screen was not loaded therefore no onPress event. I'm also wondering what's the correct way to update the state. What's wrong in my trigger to update state?

```
export default class OverviewView extends React.Component {

          constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state ={ isLoading: true,
                          watchlist: 'top20',
                          curr: 'usd'
                        }
          }


          async componentDidMount(){
            const lists = ["portfolio","watchlist"];
            const list_name = this.state.watchlist;
            const curr = this.state.curr;
            const url = 'http://sample.com/api/watchlists/'+list_name+'/overview?curr='+curr;//sample.com 
                is a sample domain but the URI applies
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const data = await response.json();
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                list_names: lists,
                dataSource: data,
                head: ['Coin','Price','Volume(24H)'],
              })
          }
        render(){
            const tableData = this.state.dataSource;
            const lists = this.state.list_names;
            if(this.state.isLoading){
              return(
                <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
                  <ActivityIndicator/>
                </View>
              )
            }

        return(

          <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>

                  {
                lists.map((name,i)  => (
                  <Button key={i}
                  style={[styles.text]}
                  onPress={this.setState({
                    watchlist: name,
                    curr: 'btc'
                  })}
                  >{name}</Button>
                ))
                }
            <Table>
              <TableWrapper>
                  <Row data={this.state.head} textStyle={styles.text} style={[styles.row, 
                       {backgroundColor: '#333333'}]}/>
                  {
                    tableData.map((row,index) => (
                      <Row key={index}
                       data={[row.coin,row.price,row.volume]}
                       textStyle={styles.text}
                        style={[styles.row, index%2 && {backgroundColor: '#333333'}]}
                        />
                    ))
                  }

              </TableWrapper>
            </Table>

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's probably caused by your `onPress` inside your Button. Your function there doesn't look correct and as such it is being called each time for your map, which causes a re-render.

Comment: I tried not using map based on your comment. I just used the button component but it's still doesn't work. It's still the same error.

Comment: `onPress={(lists) => this.setState({
                watchlist: lists[0],
                curr: 'btc'
              }) ` I tried this, the error disappeared but when I pressed, it doesn't update table values. I already checked the values for this list, it exist.

Comment: Map is not the issue. It is the function in the onPress that is your issue.

Comment: So, how to correctly write it? It doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

As you have written your onpress , it execute at the beginning of your view rendering, it does not wait for the button to be pressed.Change it like this,

```
onPress={()=>{
        this.setState({
                    watchlist: name,
                    curr: 'btc'
                  })}}
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that arrow function needs a return value. Is return doesn't need to be declared here?Why?

Comment: *needs return value if you use curly brace.

Comment: you don't have to specify return here, arrow function will handle it .